# BLE host with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need an application which is use for advertise some services.

I installed some BLE plugin from NUGet and ı readed their documentation on github. Generally they explain scanner mode, except this plugin of BluetoothLE ( https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle) .

I tried that advertiser code  :

```
      protected override void OnStart()
    {

        var server = CrossBleAdapter.Current.CreateGattServer();
        var service = server.AddService(Guid.NewGuid(), true); //ı got  error on this line


        var characteristic = service.AddCharacteristic(
            Guid.NewGuid(),
            CharacteristicProperties.Read | CharacteristicProperties.Write ,
            GattPermissions.Read | GattPermissions.Write
        );

        var notifyCharacteristic = service.AddCharacteristic
        (
            Guid.NewGuid(),
            CharacteristicProperties.Indicate | CharacteristicProperties.Notify,
            GattPermissions.Read | GattPermissions.Write
        );

        IDisposable notifyBroadcast = null;
        notifyCharacteristic.WhenDeviceSubscriptionChanged().Subscribe(e =>
        {
            var @event = e.IsSubscribed ? "Subscribed" : "Unsubcribed";

            if (notifyBroadcast == null)
            {
                this.notifyBroadcast = Observable
                    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                    .Where(x => notifyCharacteristic.SubscribedDevices.Count > 0)
                    .Subscribe(_ =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Sending Broadcast");
                        var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("g");
                        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dt);
                        notifyCharacteristic.Broadcast(bytes);
                    });
            }
        });

        characteristic.WhenReadReceived().Subscribe(x =>
        {
            var write = "HELLO";

            // you must set a reply value
            x.Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(write);

            x.Status = GattStatus.Success; // you can optionally set a status, but it defaults to Success
        });
        characteristic.WhenWriteReceived().Subscribe(x =>
        {
            var write = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x.Value, 0, x.Value.Length);
            // do something value
        });



    }
```

Error is that;

***CS1061 'IObservable' does not contain a definition of 'AddService' and no accessible extension methods 'AddService' were found that accept a first argument of type 'IObservable' (could you be missing a using directive or assembly reference?)***

What can ı do about that? Do you know another plugin can do advertiser ?

Answer (score 1):

That plugin you are using is now out of service from reading the notice on the link you included. They have now shifted the functionality over to [Shiny](https://shinylib.net/)

I would strongly recommend looking at Shiny as it has some nice documentation on how to get setup with BLE Hosting here:
https://shinylib.net/blehosting/

Given that Shiny is written by the same person that wrote the plugin you were initially trying and looking over the documentation it shouldn't be too difficult to shift to this approach as large amounts of the code looks similar if not the same.